# Prepopulating database with room creates database with wrong schema

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I need a prepopulated database in my app. *Room* correctly creates the database; but when I try to interact with it; the app crashes with `Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema` error. The schema of the generated file (from `data/data/com.myapp/databases/`) folder seems to be fine. I am using DB Browser Lite to visually create my database.

```
MESSAGE -- Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: EnglishMarathi(com.myapp.data.EnglishMarathi).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='EnglishMarathi', columns={id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, word=Column{name='word', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, meaning3=Column{name='meaning3', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, meaning2=Column{name='meaning2', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, meaning1=Column{name='meaning1', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='EnglishMarathi', columns={englishTyped=Column{name='englishTyped', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, word=Column{name='word', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, meaning3=Column{name='meaning3', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, meaning2=Column{name='meaning2', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, meaning1=Column{name='meaning1', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]} 
CAUSE -- null 
TRACE -- [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@450ced0
```

### Update 1

I have tried creating a small database file from scratch from the schema.json sql script. Still the issue is there.

```
{...
"tableName": "MarathiEnglish",
"createSql": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `${TABLE_NAME}` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `word` TEXT NOT NULL, `meaning1` TEXT NOT NULL, `meaning2` TEXT, `meaning3` TEXT, `englishTyped` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))",
...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Room it is the @Entity class that defines/determines the table that Room expects.

Your issue, according to the messages is that the Entity does not include the
**englishTyped** column that is in the pre-populated database.

So you need to either

- add the **englishTyped** column to the **EnglishMarathi** Entity (class)

  - possibly `val englishTyped: String`
    or
- remove the **englishTyped** column from the pre-populated database.

> I have tried creating a small database file from scratch from the schema.json sql script. Still the issue is there.

The simpler way is to

1. create the Entity,
2. compile the project (Ctrl + F9) and
3. using the Android View in Android Studio, find and expand the `Java (generated)` in the  Project Explorer Window.
4. Then expand the sub directorys and find the class that is the same name, but suffixed with **_Impl**, as the class that you have annotated with @Database.
5. within that class there will be a method named **`createAllTables`**, the **EXPECTED** SQL for the table(s) can be copied and pasted into DB Browser.

**Example**

Say you have the EnglishMarathi class as :-

```
@Entity
data class EnglishMarathi(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long,
    @NonNull
    val word: String,
    val meaning1: String,
    val meaning2: String?,
    val meaning3: String?,
    val englishTyped: String
)
```

and your @Database annotated class is **TheDatabase**, then after compiling the project :-

[image]